# Using TensorFlow regression to learn x^2 results in a constant for most input values

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, nonlinear-regression, tensorflow

I'd like to use TensorFlow to model a very basic function. Here, I'm trying to model x^2 (x squared). If I can get this to work, I should have no trouble getting more complicated examples to work. But for some reason, I'm stuck.

I mean, it's correct for 0^2, 1^2, and 2^2, but nothing else.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)
ys = (xs * xs).reshape(10,1)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

hidden = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x, 10, activation_fn=tf.tanh)
prediction = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(hidden, 1, activation_fn=None)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(y, prediction)))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.01).minimize(cost)

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(10000):
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: xs, y: ys})

print(sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x:xs, y: ys}))
```

The output is usually something like:

```
[[  1.43051147e-06]
 [  9.99880314e-01]
 [  3.99987650e+00]
 [  4.00000267e+01]
 [  4.00000343e+01]
 [  4.00000343e+01]
 [  4.00000343e+01]
 [  4.00000343e+01]
 [  4.00000343e+01]
 [  4.00000343e+01]]
```

But the result I'm looking for is:

```
array([[ 0],
       [ 1],
       [ 4],
       [ 9],
       [16],
       [25],
       [36],
       [49],
       [64],
       [81]])
```

If it's having this much trouble learning a simple function like x^2, how is it ever supposed to approximate a function that's more complicated?

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with how I'm using the fully_connected() method. There is probably a very good reason why none of the tutorials I can find use tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected().

If I replace that with something like this, it performs very well:

```
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1,10]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10]))

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10,1]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]))

hidden = tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1
prediction = tf.matmul(hidden, w2) + b2
```

EDIT 2:
Duh! Because I forgot to add the activation function!

Comment: You are using only one training example. How do you expect the network to learn?

Comment: How am I using only 1 training example? My intention it to use 10 training examples, each with 1 input and 1 output. Is it not going through all 10 training examples?

Comment: So let's get this straight, you're training a hidden layer with 10 nodes, *with 10 training examples*?   I think the fact that it worked for predicting y=x was more luck :D

Comment: Regarding your edit- yes, even if you just use prediction = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x, 1, activation_fn=None) with lower learning rate and 1000 sdg steps it performs better (this is basically attempting linear regresion)

Comment: Wow. Yes. I forgot to add the activation function in my edit. Oops!

I know 10 training examples isn't a lot. I was under the impression that if I didn't have very many training examples, it would still converge, but would overfit and wouldn't generalize well.

Overfitting is a problem I thought I'd tackle once I could get the network to at least correctly work for 10 examples. Baby steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network model is over specified for the few training examples you have and the SDG is getting stuck in a local optimum.

For example, I get the below from a much simpler network (3 hidden nodes, lower learning rate = 0.001, and only 1000 steps)

```
[[  0.21996975]
 [  1.61492825]
 [  2.38338852]
 [  4.91569805]
 [ 12.91742706]
 [ 23.73417664]
 [ 31.3901577 ]
 [ 43.04149628]
 [ 53.73323059]
 [ 56.74698639]]
```

Below are the fitted values for another run.  The 3 hidden tanhs are not so hidden and we see the out of sample performance for this network would be poor.
[image: Fitted values]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Yes. That makes sense!

[[ -0.28854942]
 [  1.4819355 ]
 [  4.1424942 ]
 [  8.61520767]
 [ 15.78826141]
 [ 25.43758583]
 [ 36.13232803]
 [ 48.29386139]
 [ 64.65141296]
 [ 80.61138153]]

Comment: Glad to help ( I am also learning neural networks).  Btw, just for code clarity I would not pass in the "ys" for prediction, i.e. prefer print(sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x:xs}))